# The name of the vegetable

Tags: names

[image]

What is the right name for this vegetable (see the picture above)? I usually call it a (vegetable) marrow.

Is it correct to call it a squash? (Pumpkins and courgette are types of squashes, so I would like to avoid any ambiquity.)

Comment: In AmE, most speakers would say it was a *squash*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to sound a note of caution in specifying what the vegetable is for a few reasons:

1. Vegetables can often be called different things in different places.
2. It is difficult to get a sense of the size of the vegetable from the photo.
3. There are [a few different varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_pepo) with a similar appearance, I am not able to tell you for certain which one it is.

*To me* as a Brit, that vegetable looks like (and I would call it) a **courgette** (I assume it would be zucchini in AmE, but I could be wrong). Courgettes can come in a few different colours, including dark green (the most common), light green and yellow. It could also be a [*spaghetti squash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_squash), or a courgette-spaghetti squash hybrid, but this is not a variety I have ever come across or heard of before (other than on Wikipedia while researching this answer).

*It could be* called a marrow, but marrows are much bigger (at least in the UK, [they are essentially large courgettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(vegetable))) and it doesn't look that big. Most British people would mainly associate a dark green variety with the word *marrow*.

I would never call it simply a *squash*, even it is technically one, because to me (and most Brits) that means a *butternut squash*.

Answer (score 1):

This type of plant is called "**a squash**" and the one shown in the image is "**[a marrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(vegetable))**"

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zucchini) says that this variety of squash is called **Zucchini** *(/zuːˈkiːniː/, American English)* or **courgette** *(/kʊərˈʒɛt/, British English)*, however, I disagree, it doesn't look like **Zucchini** at all.

*Ps. In Russian it is "**Кабачок**"*

Comment: It's not a zucchini, since zucchini are dark green. I agree with you on this.

Comment: That's exactly why I disagree with Wikipedia.

Comment: It looks like a courgette/zucchini to me, they come in a few different colours.